# How to show route map between multiple points?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

**In react-native How can we show the route map between multiple points?
I want to show the route map between 3 or 4 points in the react-native application.**

I referred to google maps API and used
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
but I was able to show the route map between two points only. How can we show the route map by connecting three or four points in react-native maps?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: see my answer use https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions

Answer (score 0):

use react-native-maps-directions to show directions between multiple points. It shows direction between max 4 to 5 points only. if you want to show more than 5 pints maybe you should purchase api key.

https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions

Answer (score 0):

Use waypoints property of DirectionsRenderer